# UnsupportedOperationException with DriverManager.getConnection() on Android

Tags: java, android, mysql, jdbc

I am unable to connect JDBC to my database, getting following error

```
Error :  E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.example.myprojectapplication, PID: 32686
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myprojectapplication/com.example.myprojectapplication.MainActivity}:
 java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
 Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
     at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:383)
     at com.mysql.cj.conf.ConnectionUrlParser.isConnectionStringSupported(ConnectionUrlParser.java:152)
     at com.mysql.cj.conf.ConnectionUrl.acceptsUrl(ConnectionUrl.java:258)
     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:187)
     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:569)
     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:219)
     at com.example.myprojectapplication.ObjectClass.JDBC.CONN(JDBC.java:19)
     at com.example.myprojectapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:72)
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

```
package com.example.myprojectapplication.ObjectClass;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;


public class JDBC {

    public void CONN() {
        Connection con = null;

        try {
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/prog";
            String username = "root";
            String password = "mysql";

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);

            if (con != null) {
                System.out
                        .println("Successfully connected to MySQL database test");
            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out
                    .println("An error occurred while connecting MySQL databse");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedOperationException exa){
            exa.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the full exception stacktrace (and please, [edit] your question to add information, don't use comments).

Comment: Ok thanks , i do it ! @MarkRotteveel

Comment: Could you please add the code from the MainActivity class. The exception is not thrown from you Connection class.

Comment: Do you have MySql Jar/Dependency available in your project?

Comment: @SwaritAgarwal Yes, I added it in the dependencies --> "  implementation files('libs/mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar')"

Comment: @AndreiTigau This is not from my MainActivity because after running this part, it issues an error and does not execute the rest of the code contained in the MainActivity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the stacktrace, the MySQL Connector/J version you are using is using a `java.util.regex.Matcher` feature not supported on Android (probably [named groups](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-j/blob/release/8.0/src/main/core-api/java/com/mysql/cj/conf/ConnectionUrlParser.java#L152)). The workaround is to use a 5.1.x version of MySQL Connector/J instead of a 8.0.x version.

However, you shouldn't use JDBC from Android applications. It is insecure, and generally badly performing to connect to a database directly. The proper solution is to write a REST service (or other form of webservice) to mediate between your Android application and the database.

Comment: Ok ok it seems to me a good solution but what is actually a service and how to create one?

Comment: @MatClt https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer

Comment: Yes, of course, but often they already exist, should we create one? maybe it's a stupid question mdrr

Answer (score 0):

I might be late to answer this, but after many hours of trying different solutions just as I was going to give up on android and jconnector I tried bellow and it worked for me.

**To use jconnector from Android application to connect to a MySQL remote server that runs MySQL version 8 and/or 5.7 this solution worked for me:**

Note that older versions of jconnector than the one I am suggesting here will not work with a remote MySQL 8 server!

I tried to use mysql-connector-java-8.xxx.jar with "`com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`" but it did not work either on an Android application. it will only work if you use java swing or other java applications and again "not on android"!

**SOLUTION for android:**

1. Download /or import **mysql-connector-java-5.1.49.jar** as your connector jar file and replace it with your connector class! (note that versions bellow this will/may not work!)
2. Use this connector class: `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();`

Answer (score -1):

Probably means that the msql driver information in your configuration does not match the load driver in your code. The high version of the mysql driver registration, try to use this method: Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");